# Field expansion with 'since' and 'until' for insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get a subset of adsets with the corresponding insights for a specific daterange (2015-11-01 to 2015-11-30)

```
my_campaign_id/?fields=campaign,insights.fields(impressions)
.since(1463752380).until(1463752380)
```

but I get back

```
"insights": {
"data": [
  {
    "impressions": "1470",
    "date_start": "2015-11-30",
    "date_stop": "2015-12-01"
  }
],
```

which is wrong because it's counting impressions for Dec 1st too, in fact date_stop is "2015-12-01" and not "2015-11-30".
What't the correct way of filtering expanded fields? I couldn't find any other way in the documentation/forums.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation under time_range says that unix timestamp is not supported. You have to use isoformat instead, referring to the local time of you timezone. But I have to admit I have seen an error message that stated that the time had to be defined in isoformat OR unix time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.6

Anyway, try this:

```
<campaign_id>/insights?fields=impressions&time_range[since]=2015-11-01&time_range[until]=2015-11-30
```